# Passport-azure-ad passport plug-in refresh the token

Tags: passport.js, openid, outlook-addin, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm currently working on an outlook add-in using the MS Graph API. In this add-in, I'm using azuread-openidconnect passport plug-in to authenticate the users using the OIDC strategy on the Azure-AD V2 endpoint.

I'm running into the typical issue where my access token is expired, and I need to use my refresh token to get an up to date access token. From the docks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) I can easily check and refresh the token manually. However, I assume that this functionality has been baked into the passport plug-in. If so how do I go about checking and refreshing the token with the plug-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no method in [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) for that. Passport's role is to authorize the initial access token, which can then be used to access APIs (including the refresh token API) at the provider.

So you may need to refresh these tokens by yourself, or by using a separate library like [passport-oauth2-refresh](https://github.com/fiznool/passport-oauth2-refresh).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? I don't see how I can refresh access token, if I don't get refresh token back from `passport-azure-ad`?

Comment: @Perp the refreshToken is passed to the callback along with the accessToken. see example on [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-ad)